# Was God responsible for condoning the Jewish leaders to be stubborn in Mark 3:5?

Tags: mark

Mark 3:5 (NIV) says that Jesus looked around at them in anger and, deeply distressed at their stubborn hearts. Now, if God is ultimately responsible for condoning (Lamentations 3:37-38), could it be possible that Jesus was angry at whoever was responsible for allowing the Jewish leaders to be so stubborn?
Could Jesus have been subconsciously angry at God for allowing the Jewish leaders to have such a close-minded corrupt way of thinking?

Comment: This is a question that solicits an opinion and is not asking about what a text says or attempting to elucidate the meaning of the text.

Comment: @Robert, Hermeneutics is concerned with what Mark 3:5 is trying to tell us within the context of Lamentations 3:37-38. If you understand that God is not directly responsible for the corruption of the Jewish Leaders, but ultimately responsible for everything, then you might see that I'm not condemning God. For, as we overcome all the corruption, we have a deeper appreciation for God's Love. Correct me if I am wrong, but I believe Lamentations 3:37-38 is about God allowing or condoning. If you can prove that my moral framework is not based on scripture, I would love make improvements.

Comment: Stevie, a vote to close signifies the question needs more work. If you think you can tie Mark 3:5 to lamentations 3:37-38, then please update the question and spell out exactly what the connection is, but I think you are going to have a *very* hard time doing that without throwing in tons of personal opinions and judgments. E.g. there is no natural connection that isn't based on personal opinion and speculation, and thus all the answers will be based on personal opinion as well. If you want to tie hardness of heart into something from the old testament, use Is 6.9-10 and show your work

Comment: From the BH site guidelines: 'Some subjective questions are allowed, but “subjective” does not mean “anything goes”. All subjective questions are expected to be constructive."
Hermeneutics is not an exact science so I believe this site should lean toward inclusiveness regarding what is "opinion-based."  see this: https://stackoverflow.blog/2010/09/29/good-subjective-bad-subjective/

Comment: while the question indeed solicits opinions it also invites hermeneutical work. I gave it an upvote. @StevieC. perhaps you should edit the question to satisfy those who oppose it. Ask for biblical evidence pro or con; stipulate that answers should be based on data from the bible or other experts, not just opinion. I hope that those who object don't do so simply because it challenges traditional assumptions. This is a "secular site" and difficult questions should be welcome.

Answer (score 1):

This is a perpetual question, "Is God responsible for all calamities and good things?". I would definitely answer "Yes". But wait, don't jump too fast your conclusion!

Let me first ask another question, "If you knew something bad was going to happen, and you knew how to intervene from its happening but you didn't take action. Do you think you should be responsible for the bad thing happened?"

The Lord took the ownership, not because He caused it, but He allowed it. Human borne to have different degree of disobedience. Our history were wars, killings, conspiracy, deception, everywhere without boundary.  We should be grateful that the human race can survive until now, if not divine intervene at His time to restore the order.

Was God responsible for the Jewish Leaders their heart remained stubborn? Let's review these verses

> Make the heart of this people calloused;
> make their ears dull
> and close their eyes.
> Otherwise they might see with their eyes,
> hear with their ears,
> understand with their hearts,
> and turn and be healed.” (Isaiah 6:10 NIV)
>
> I will give you a new heart and put a new spirit in you; I will remove from you your heart of stone and give you a heart of flesh. (Ezekiel 36:26 NIV)

So yes, the Lord is responsible, and it is His sovereignty whether He let the evils remain evil (Isaiah 6:10), or save the penitent (Ezekiel 36:26).

However, if we realized we were in a calamity, there is a promise. For whoever see with their eyes, hear with their ears, understand with their hearts, turn and get the good things.

Comment: Indeed, God is responsible and had a solution in mind before making anything. +1